# Visualizing a cuboid in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-animation

I am buiding an application to visualize an industrial process. I thought it would be nice to have a 3D-ish view of this process instead of a top down view. I am trying to show a long lane (the shape of a cuboid) and came up with the following code.

```
class Lane extends StatelessWidget {
  const Lane({
    super.key,
  });

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Stack(
      children: [
        Transform(
          transform: Matrix4.identity()
            ..translate(-462, -50,0),
          child: Transform(
            transform: Matrix4.skewY(pi/3),
            child: Container(
              height: 50,
              width: 462,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: Colors.grey,
                  border: Border.all(color: onsZwart)
              ),
              child: Center(child: Text("")),
            ),
          ),
        ),
        Transform(
          transform: Matrix4.identity()
          ..translate(-462, -50,0),
          child: Transform(
            transform: Matrix4.skewX(pi/6),
            child: Container(
              height: 800,
              width: 150,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: Colors.grey,
                  border: Border.all(color: onsZwart)
              ),
              child: Center(child: Text("Top")),
            ),
          ),
        ),

        Transform(transform: Matrix4.identity()
          ..translate(0, 750,0),

          child: Container(
            height: 50,
            width: 150,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              color: Colors.grey,
              border: Border.all(color: onsZwart)
            ),
            child: Center(child: Text("Front")),
          ),
        ),

      ],
    );
  }
}
```

which results in the following image:
[Cuboid visual](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uR2j2.png).

My question is the following:

1. Is there a better way to make a cuboid type shape? Since this implementation seems to be far from the optimal/intended way to draw such a shape
2. if i try to wrap the containers in an Inkwell or GestureDetector, the collission breaks. Is there an alternative way to make the shape clickable?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Have a nice day.